# Related to GUI creation using Swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, events, frames, panels

I am facing problem during event handling.

The problem is like this:

1. My GUI has `mainPanel` (JPanel) which in turn consists of a panel with three buttons (namely `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3`) at its WEST position.
2. I have created 3 more panels namely `pnl1`, `pnl2`, `pnl3` (each panel has one label and one text area) using three different functions of same class.
3. My requirement is that if I click `btn1` / `btn2` / `btn3` then `pnl1` / `pnl2` / `pnl3`  respectively must appear at `mainPanel`'s CENTER position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to add action listener to the btn1, btn2, btn3. Then when the respective button is clicked you write a function that will display the required respective panels to the center of GUI. 
To do so you can use cardLayout.

If you add detail to your question then we can help you with better answer or suggestions.

What's the purpose of the label and text area? 
Add a screenshot of your GUI and some code that you have written.

Comment: I used the card layout and my problem is solved.Thank you very much subash

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want to put a CardLayout in the center, here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could consider creating a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` for the CENTER panel. The `CardLayout` could contain 4 UI's ( the `pnl1`,`pnl2`,`pnl3` and an empty panel ), and clicking on those buttons could activate the correct panel on the `CardLayout`

Comment: I used the card layout and my problem is solved.Thank you very much robin

Comment: In that case you might accept the answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)